# How to write a mtl-like framework that is sensitive to monad composition order?

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

[mtl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) doesn't care that much about the order of the monads in the monad stack, as long as there is a viable implementation. For example:

```
foo :: (MonadError () m, MonadState Int m) => m ()
foo = (put 1 >> throwError ()) `catchError` return

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ runExcept $ flip execStateT 0 $ foo -- returns Right 0
    print $ flip execState 0 $ runExceptT $ foo -- returns 1
```

Suppose I wanted to create a mini-mtl framework (for the sake of simplicity, one which covered only [`ExceptT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Except.html) and [`StateT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Strict.html)) that was sensitive to the order of composition, and let me express things like

> this function requires an error effect with priority over the
>   state effect, but I'm letting you choose the exact error and state
>   implementations.

or

> this function requires a state effect with priority over the
>   error effect, but I'm letting you choose the exact error and state
>   implementations.

in such a way that only the stacks with the correct order had the required instances.

I don't know how to embed effect priority in the typeclass constraints. Would I need some kind of "constraint transformer" of kind `Constraint -> Constraint`? Perhaps some constraint parameterized by a type-level list of constraints?

Comment: Can't you just make a `NewExceptT` and `NewStateT` then give one (and only one) of the two instances `instance MonadState m => NewExceptT e m` or `instance MonadExcept m => NewStateT s m`?

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson Yes; I was only wondering if it could be done in a more general way.

Comment: Here's a possible solution: https://pay.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/6jk3vy/a_tale_of_two_brackets/djim0le/